# Android Device Location from Ethernet

Tags: android, geolocation, location, ethernet

I've a TI OMAP platform running Kitkat 4.4.4. The platform doesn't have Wifi/GPS/Cellular connection but it has ethernet. I use eth1 to access internet.

Is there anyway to determine the coarse geographical location of the device based on eth1. I tried the sample code below, but it fails for ethernet connection.

```
/** Check if we can get our location */
public void checkLocation(){
    // Get the location manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

    try{
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 1");}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 2");}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {Log.d(TAG,"location found 3");}
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Location Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Above code throws `provider doesn't exist: network` exception for ethernet. Works OK on a device with wifi/GPS.

I've also set the following permissions in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Any ideas how to determine location if the device has on ethernet connectivity?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

and

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

to check the availability of your network or gps. If these two return false to you, then you might not be able to use the locationManager to find location.